# Возможно ли запускать стороннее андроид приложение не покидая своего?

Tags: java, c#, android, unity3d, плагин

я хотел бы узнать, возможно ли запускать другие `Android` приложения не выходя из моего? если быть точнее, то у меня есть `Unity` приложение, в котором нужно запускать например какую-то игру, и по верх этой игры наложить небольшую кнопку, нажав на которую я смогу вернуться в мое приложение... Видел как такое делают запуская веб страницу: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1hLo5C50wE&t=147s  - мне нужно почти тоже самое, только не с веб страницей, а просто - со сторонним приложением)

Comment: Да, можно. Запуск приложения через интернет. И кнопка поверх всех окон

Comment: Здравствуйте, Arty Morris! а не через интернет нельзя? речь идет не об открытии веб страницы, а об обычном запуске Android приложения, и наложения поверх него кнопки... Типа игру какую-то на телефоне установленную запустить из моего приложения...

Comment: Я понял. Можно. Изучайте интенты

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем здравствуйте! Я нашел ответ вот здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60454766/how-to-create-an-overlay-window-to-show-over-all-apps-on-android-10

Если ссылка перестанет быть рабочей, то вы можете просмотреть код ниже =) Этот кусочек кода вы можете вставить в Ваш метод, который запускает стороннее приложение:

```
 params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                                LayoutParamFlags,
                                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
                        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.END;
                        windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
                        mDisplay = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
                        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                        layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ngk_overlay, null);
                        windowManager.addView(layoutView, params);
```

конкретно в моем случае в  `context` находится:

```
 currentActivity = UnityPlayer.currentActivity;
 Context context = currentActivity.getApplicationContext();
```

`layout` - я так понял это то что будет отображаться поверх всех окон на Вашем смартфоне(надеюсь более опытные программисты меня если что поправят)))

Также можете добавить этот метод в Ваш Java класс. Он при закрытии Вашего приложения удаляет тот объект который Вы наложили поверх всех окон):

```
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        windowManager.removeView(layoutView);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Для запуска сторонних приложений я использую этот код

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setPackage(имя пакета);

        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
        Collections.sort(resolveInfos, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));

        if (resolveInfos.size() > 0) {
            try {
                ResolveInfo launchable = resolveInfos.get(0);
                ActivityInfo activity = launchable.activityInfo;
                ComponentName name = new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                i.setComponent(name);
                startActivity(i);
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(имя пакета);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за Ваш ответ! Я добавил свой ответ на мой вопрос :)